# How to change the main window widgets with Python/Glade?

Tags: python, user-interface, glade

I am more or less new to GUI programming (just some tiny bit of Perl/Tk experience); I am new to Python, and I am new to Glade, both of which I would like to learn how to use.

I have a program in mind which would require one single window, but this window's contents (widgets and all) would have to change with each step that the user has completed (like in one of the installers for Windows/Mac where you keep clicking "Next"). The trouble is that already now (at the no-code-stage) I am stumped for how to tackle this. I have tried googling, but I don't seem to even know the right keywords. It would be great if someone on here could help me out with a link to a tutorial covering that "Next-thing" or at least with one or two helpful keywords.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glade allows you to create partial windows. Example: You can create many `GtkVBox`'es with the contents you want, and then in runtime swap between them.

In fact, glade already includes [`GtkAssistant`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkassistant.html), *"a widget used to guide users through multi-step operations. It includes tools to ease implementing the "next-next-finish" style of dialogs. Each step is generally handled by one assistant page. The assistant controls the page flow to collect the necessary data to complete the application task."*

Try to use it, and tell us how it goes, preferably by asking another, more specific question, if you have problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for telling me about GtkAssistant, it seems to do exactly what I've been looking for!