# How to make a one-window program with GTK, python and glade?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, gtk3

I'd like to write a program that has one main window and if I click on a button it changes the content of the window (or something similar) and the user can go back after that to the "home page".
I'm using python3, gtk3 and glade on Ubuntu 19.04.

Here's the example.glade XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.22.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkApplicationWindow" id="main">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkButton" id="button">
        <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <property name="receives_default">True</property>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

And here's the Python3 file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gi
import os
os.chdir('/home/sources')
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class app:

  def __init__(self):
    self.gladefile = 'example.glade'
    self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
    self.builder.add_from_file(self.gladefile)
    self.builder.connect_signals(self)
    self.window = self.builder.get_object('main')
    elf.window = self.builder.get_object('button')
    self.window.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main = app()
  Gtk.main()
```

I'd like to change the window (but in the same window) to this when the button is pressed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.22.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkApplicationWindow" id="main">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkNotebook" id="notebook">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="but1">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
          </object>
        </child>
        <child type="tab">
          <object class="GtkLabel">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">page 1</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="tab_fill">False</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="but2">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child type="tab">
          <object class="GtkLabel">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">page 2</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="position">1</property>
            <property name="tab_fill">False</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="but3">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="position">2</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child type="tab">
          <object class="GtkLabel">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">page 3</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="position">2</property>
            <property name="tab_fill">False</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Comment: Show us the code you have already, so we don't have to duplicate your efforts.

Comment: Also read up on [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I've uploaded an example but it really does nothing, so it probably won't help much. However I also wrote the concept of what I'd like to make, maybe it'll help.

Comment: Also here's a similar question, and it has an answer but I'd like to know how GtkAssistant changes the window content in runtime. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361364/how-to-change-the-main-window-widgets-with-python-glade

Comment: If you need help on a Gtk.Assistant specifically, please post another question. I answered in what I thought was the best answer for what you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using [Gtk.Stack](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStack.html)

The glade file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.22.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkImage" id="image1">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="stock">gtk-go-back</property>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">window</property>
    <property name="window_position">center</property>
    <property name="default_width">500</property>
    <property name="default_height">400</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="on_window_destroy" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkStack" id="stack">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="home_button">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Notebook page</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="button_clicked" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="name">page0</property>
            <property name="title" translatable="yes">page0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkBox" id="notebook_box">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Home</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                <property name="image">image1</property>
                <property name="always_show_image">True</property>
                <signal name="clicked" handler="home_clicked" swapped="no"/>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">0</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkNotebook" id="notebook">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkButton" id="but1">
                    <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                    <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                  </object>
                </child>
                <child type="tab">
                  <object class="GtkLabel">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <property name="label" translatable="yes">page 1</property>
                  </object>
                  <packing>
                    <property name="tab_fill">False</property>
                  </packing>
                </child>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkButton" id="but2">
                    <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                    <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                  </object>
                  <packing>
                    <property name="position">1</property>
                  </packing>
                </child>
                <child type="tab">
                  <object class="GtkLabel">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <property name="label" translatable="yes">page 2</property>
                  </object>
                  <packing>
                    <property name="position">1</property>
                    <property name="tab_fill">False</property>
                  </packing>
                </child>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkButton" id="but3">
                    <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                    <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                  </object>
                  <packing>
                    <property name="position">2</property>
                  </packing>
                </child>
                <child type="tab">
                  <object class="GtkLabel">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <property name="label" translatable="yes">page 3</property>
                  </object>
                  <packing>
                    <property name="position">2</property>
                    <property name="tab_fill">False</property>
                  </packing>
                </child>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">True</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="name">page1</property>
            <property name="title" translatable="yes">page1</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

The python file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk


UI_FILE = "file.glade"

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):

        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file(UI_FILE)
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)

        window = self.builder.get_object('window')
        window.show_all()

    def on_window_destroy(self, window):
        Gtk.main_quit()

    def home_clicked (self, button):
        stack = self.builder.get_object('stack')
        home_button = self.builder.get_object('home_button')
        stack.set_visible_child(home_button)

    def button_clicked (self, button):
        stack = self.builder.get_object('stack')
        notebook_box = self.builder.get_object('notebook_box')
        stack.set_visible_child(notebook_box)

app = GUI()
Gtk.main()
```